# Get list of clients in a room socketio version 4.1.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, android-room

I want to get list of clients in a specific room. I try some function I found but It's not work for me.
I know
`socket.adapter.rooms` return all rooms with client in rooms so I try:

```
console.log(socket.adapter.rooms[idroom]);
```

But it returns `undefined`. My socketio version is 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

```
var clients = io.sockets.clients('your_room'); // all clients from room 'your_room'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.